# How can I send a signal to a process using its pid from inside the kernel (not from the user space)

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, signals, kill-process

I am writing a new syscall where I want to send a kill(pid, SIGSTOP) signal to a process that I just created in order to move it from the runqueue to the waitqueue. Then, I can wake it up again using kill(pid, SIGCONT).

The problem is that the kill is only used from the userspace, how can I send a signal from inside the kernel itself?  is there an equivalent function to use that can do so?
I found kill_pid, but I don't know how its headers should be included.

Comment: Signals can be generated at any time, but are only delivered when the process is being scheduled, not when it is running. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1860175/1216776 for some details.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you found the correct method of sending a signal to a process from kernel space - `kill_pid` which is also exported, which means it is available to kernel modules.
Using elixir - lets look at some usage [examples](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/C/ident/kill_pid) - this shows you in which header file the symbol is defined - so you should start by including `sched/signal.h` and do the process for any other dependencies you may have